# Combine colorbox with hoverIntent

Tags: jquery, colorbox, hoverintent

My client wants the pop-ups to appear on hover, but not immediately. HoverIntent seems ideal, but I can't figure out how to use it with my pop-up function, colorbox.

Here's my jQuery code so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
$(".popup").colorbox({
    inline:true,
    scrolling:false
});
});
```

How do I bring hoverintent - which has a syntax like this: 
`$("#demo2 li").hoverIntent( makeTall, makeShort )`

Thanks - Joe

Answer (score 0):

**Example 1:**

To open colorbox with hoverIntent use the "open" property and define the colorbox object in hoverIntent's open callback (the "makeTall" function).  The out callback will fire as soon as the colorbox opens (and forces mouseout), so you may not need hoverIntent's out callback (the "makeShort" function). Even so hoverIntent requires a function as the second argument, so just send an empty function.

```
$(function() {

    $(".popup").hoverIntent(function() {
        $(this).colorbox({
            inline: true,
            scrolling:false,
            open:true
        })
    }, function(){});

});
```

See the complete example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/DonamiteIsTNT/gcW6m/5/embedded/result/).

**Example 2 - Seperating declarations:**

Alternatively, if you prefer to keep all of your colorbox declarations somewhere else, you can seperate the declaration from the hoverIntent() like so:

```
$(function() {
    //colorbox definitions
    $(".popup").colorbox({
        inline: true,
        scrolling:false
    });

    //gallery code
    $(".popup").hoverIntent(function() {
        $(this).colorbox({ open:true })
    }, function(){});
});
```

**Example 3** - Changing the "over" delay:

By default, hoverIntent uses a delay of 100ms to run the "over" callback. Send a key-value object instead of 2 functions in order to use a different delay.

```
$(function() {
    $(".popup").hoverIntent({
        over: function() {
            $(this).colorbox({
                inline: true,
                scrolling:false,
                open:true
            })
        },
        out: function(){},
        //the interval option defines the over-callback delay
        interval: 1000
    });
});
```

Fyi, as you mentioned there is a `timeout` option, but that will define the out-callback delay.  When used with colorbox, however, the timer for the "out" callback will start as soon as colorbox is opened (due to the popup forcing the mouseout).  It's worth keeping in mind if you need something to happen, say, 3 seconds after your colorbox window is opened, but is otherwise useless when used with a full window popup.

Comment: As usual, I was a little too quick on the trigger. How would I incorporate a hoverIntent parameter (like timeout:1000) in the first code sample?